# SQLiteException: cannot start a transaction within a transaction (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlexception

I'm having a problem finishing an SQLite transaction and I'm totally baffled on how to do it. It totally looks like [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/storm/+bug/136771) from 2007.

I'm creating my `employee` table (which references another table `entity`) as follows (edited for brevity):

```
CREATE TABLE employee (_id INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ( _id ) , 
FOREIGN KEY (_id) REFERENCES entity(_id)  ON DELETE cascade ON UPDATE cascade DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED )
```

Then I run a transaction as follows (using a `SQLiteDatabase` object, I also report status for transaction in log):

```
>> In transaction: false
beginTransaction();
>> In transaction: true
doSomeWrongINSERT();
setTransactionSuccessful();
endTransaction();
>> In transaction: false
SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed (code 19)
```

Ok, all normal. Now if I try to start a new transaction or rollback, both fail:

```
>> In transaction: false
beginTransaction();
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: cannot start a transaction within a transaction (code 1)
```

---

```
>> In transaction: false
endTransaction();
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because there is no current transaction.
```

Please note all this did not happen if FKs are immediate instead of deferred.

---

Bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37001653

Comment: Are you sure `endTransaction()` runs in your code under all circumstances, even when exceptions are thrown ? i.e. is transaction end inside a `finally` block ?

Comment: @S.D. Yes, always executed, it's in a finally block.

Comment: @S.D. In case it was not executed, then the rollback would not fail anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround: close the DB and open it again. That will update the transaction status correctly.

I still reported to Android as issue [nº74751](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74751).

Comment: I wonder why they marked the issue as "Won't fix (Obsolete)".

Comment: @Pablo They do that many times. I understand they have more important issues to worry about.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a bug in Android.
In the [SQLiteSession class](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteSession.java), `endTransactionUnchecked` clears its transaction state (`mTransactionStack`) before the `COMMIT` is executed, and does not expect that the database's transaction might still be active.
(I don't think this can ever happen without a deferred constraint.)

Submit [a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

To summarise the answers (thanks to to: @CL & @m0skit0 ) it worth recovering the transaction status in case of any exception inside `endTransaction`. This can be done in a centric place if to override `applyBatch` of your `ContentProvider` implementation:

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ContentProviderResult[] applyBatch(@NonNull ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations) throws OperationApplicationException {

        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();    // automatically opens db, if closed.
        try {
            db.beginTransaction();
            ContentProviderResult[] results = super.applyBatch(operations);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            return results;
        } finally {
            try{
                db.endTransaction();
            }catch (Throwable e2){
                //Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Failed to close a db transaction. The only way to recover is to close the db.", e2);
                db.close();
                throw e2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should catch the specific exceptions that are causing the problem, and you should never catch `Throwable` since [`Error` is not meant to be caught](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html).